# graphical layout not working in eclipse with adt 10.1

Tags: android, eclipse

i am using eclipse with adt 10.1 for android development. i making the xml files via coding. whenever i switch over to the graphical layout to see how what i have written looks, sometimes the graphical layout does not show anything.

why does this happen. and how do i solve this?

thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show an example of the exact content of the layout XML that you are trying to view in the graphical view that does not render properly?

Comment: You can also try change android version at top left menu ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just right click on the .XML file and choose Android layout editor you well get it.
And there are more options available so you can use any one of those.

Answer (score 27):

Yes, this is a strange problem with eclipse I believe. Try this out,

Right click your XML file and select **openwith->android layout editor**

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 21):

this is an odd problem, and strangely, has a simple solution, (none that were mentioned above worked)..

**CLOSE ECLIPSE 'n START AGAIN,**

Removing a project from the workspace and then importing it again didn't really work for me..

im using 64-bit windows.. that could be a reason.

Comment: And what do ya know. This worked. I was really upset b/c I thought this was a stupid answer b/c It was the first thing I tried. Guess not. +1

Comment: Worked from me. I moved my projects from an old workspace to another drive and it had to recreate .metadata which may have caused it I guess. Fine though after restart. Nice. Now, let's code!

Answer (score 14):

I was having this problem, and found that the combo box on the top right side of the Graphical Layout screen was empty.  If I selected a version of Android in this combo box, the layout would show up.
This seems to be caused, at least for me, by selecting a Google APIs Project Build Target rather than one of the Android X.X ones.  This setting is in **Properties->Android**.

Comment: I saw this issue too. In my case I used Google APIs to make use of the GeoPoint class. I had to switch targeting back to Android's and restart Eclipse to get graphical layouting working again...

Answer (score 2):

I had to update my ADT-Eclipse-Plugins through Help->Find Updates... That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As **None The Wiser** wrote. In my case I hadn't this top right corner empty but I had to **mark it again** (my target device in top right corner of grapihcal layout editor).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. But some how i was able to generate graphical view.

Go to window tab in eclipse and then click android SDK manager. Check for any update available. Most probably

> `android SDK platform tools and android SDK tools`

update will be available.Update it and your eclipse will work fine.I think it happens due to compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

I try the above but it doesn't work for me but simple restarting the eclipse solve my issue, Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In the menubar goto Project>Clean Select "Clean all projects" and then load the xml again choose your version of android.

This should do. If not try selecting other options.

Worked for me!