# android eclipse cant get my xml layout to load

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, layout, load

when i try and view my xml code in graphical layout its just blank I've tried every think on the link below and it still doesn't work any advice would help.

[graphical layout not working in eclipse with adt 10.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848385/graphical-layout-not-working-in-eclipse-with-adt-10-1)

Comment: Are there any errors/warnings in your xml file? If you could post your xml code, that might help us answer your question.

Comment: No there's no errors or anything it some times does it, and happens to all my projects and then some times it works, I've heard its some think to do with eclipse.