# Grahical View of Android Layout not showing in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I am not able to see graphic layout view in Android:  I recently imported my android projects into a new workspace and now I cannot see the graphical layout as before? I see instead an empty pallet, some editing config options and empty dropdowns.  what the #$$&^#($ happened?

Comment: Refer this, http://stackoverflow.com/q/5848385/603744

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the latest version of ADT. You can try selecting a different SDK version in the top-right corner of the layout-view. The pallet should appear. If your layout still doesn't show, try dragging a random component from the pallet into the layout.

Comment: As I said, change the SDK-Version (e.g. from "Android 2.2" to "Android 2.1") in the upper right-hand corner of the layout-view, and the pallet will appear. Then, drag a random component into the layout. Also try changing the device screen size in the top left-hand corner.