# Not able to open graphical editor view in android ADT 16.0.0

Tags: android, layout, editor

Went through many posts I found on the graphical editor problem I am facing. Not able to get an answer. Here is the issue

I am using Android ADT 16.0.0 and I am able to open the graphical editor but not able to see the user interface view. The app on the whole builds and works fine on the simulator. It is annooying to use only XML editor.

I installed this environment by copying the SDK, ADT plugins separately from a successful installtion. It looks as though something related to the Android Layout Editor is missing. The error thrown is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.updateFontObject(Paint_Delegate.java:1053)
    at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.reset(Paint_Delegate.java:1039)
    at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.<init>(Paint_Delegate.java:991)
    at android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.native_init(Paint_Delegate.java:614)
    at android.graphics.Paint.native_init(Paint.java)
    at android.graphics.Paint.<init>(Paint.java:194)
    at android.graphics.Paint.<init>(Paint.java:184)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:278)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:116)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:227)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:318)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:372)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1323)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1077)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ConfigListener.onConfigurationChange(GraphicalEditorPart.java:497)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationComposite.onDeviceConfigChange(ConfigurationComposite.java:2119)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationComposite.access$7(ConfigurationComposite.java:2111)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.configuration.ConfigurationComposite$5.widgetSelected(ConfigurationComposite.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

First look I guessed the layout editor files were missing. Any thougths on how to get around it??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848385/graphical-layout-not-working-in-eclipse-with-adt-10-1/6567319#6567319

Comment: yeah checked this out before. My problem is I have never managed to see the graphical layout on this installation.