# Blank Layout Editor

Tags: android, eclipse

I have this problem when I go to ADT Eclipse (Mac):

[image]

This is the XML:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@+id/action_logout" android:title="@string/menu_logout_label"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/action_edit_friends" android:title="@string/menu_edit_friends"></item>
<item android:id="@+id/action_camera" android:title="@string/menu_camera_label" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_camera"></item>
</menu>
```

I have tried the following:

```
1. Help -> Check for updates (no updates found)
2. Android SDK manager -> install all 'Tools' (all are installed)
3. Restarting Eclipse (no effect)
4. Reinstalling Eclipse (no effect)
```

Is there any solution that I haven't tried that will fix this error? I hate Eclipse.

Comment: what is the warning in the MainActivity window? also try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848385/graphical-layout-not-working-in-eclipse-with-adt-10-1

Comment: Now you may have just forgotten to include it, but does your xml have a close tag for `<menu>`?

Comment: its just that i imported more libraries than i am supposed to

Comment: @AndrewSchuster yes there is a closing tag