# Eclipse with ADT plugin - layout editor doesn't show content (stuck on "Loading editor")

Tags: java, android, eclipse, layout, adt

I'm facing a very strange issue on Eclipse with Android ADT plugin.

When I try to open an XML layout file, the result is the one in the screenshot. 
The Layout editor doesn't show the file name and no content is loaded. The editor stuck on "Loading editor" and if I switch to view, the XML is loaded fine.

This issue is raising up with every layout file and with every project I open.
I tried to:

- restart Eclipse
- update the ADT plugin
- install all the packages and updates from the Android SDK Manager

no errors are shown in the console.

[image: screenshot1]

**UPDATE**

Now Eclipse is showing a pop-up error "An error has occurred. See error log for more details.java.lang.NullPointerException" when I try to open any Layout XML file.

Comment: Try doing a `Project/Clean` - I assume that R won't be recreated. Then, you have some issue in your xml files or in your resources file names. So you will know where to look.

Comment: I tried to clean all the projects in my workspace, but the issue remain. This issue has been raised after I added a new project in my workspace.

Comment: Check this question: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848385/graphical-layout-not-working-in-eclipse-with-adt-10-1

Might help you

Comment: It seems that the newly added project is the cause.

Comment: I've already seen that question and I followed every steps, but the issue remains. I tried to delete the newly added project, but nothing changed :(

Comment: What version of eclipse to you have ? If you are using old eclipse maybe it will be worth to update

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

At the right side of the image you attached click the android logo with 19 a drop down list will open select some different version...

*selecting 20 works for me*

**Solution 2**

right click layout file in the Package Explorer view and click

**Open With -> Android Layout Editor**

Comment: sorry to hear that...
well let us get cracking to find the solution then !!

Answer (score 0):

- Right-click on your project and close all unrelated projects. Keep only one project opened at any one time.
- Close all your perspectives and then open only a Java perspective.
- Ensure that there is indeed a UCApplicationTheme that it has access to, otherwise change it to a different theme.
- Restart Eclipse. Then restart your computer.
- Then try opening a default layout from a newly generated blank Android project. Do not open the layout of a web view, even if you normally develop on Phone Gap/Cordova. Let's eliminate the web view as a possible problem.
- When all else fails, reinstall Eclipse, the SDK, and ADT, completely from scratch.

And if you do get a NullPointerException, please be specific. Cut and paste on here the exact error it's giving you.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is you did update only android development tools from developer tool..
so you need to update the whole packages which are provided by the eclipse market..
Go to help-->install new software-->add the Repository-->and select all check boxes which are available in the developer tool...

Its works for me..